# Curl Multiline on Command Windows 10

Tags: windows, curl, command, windows-10

How i can send multiline via curl on Windows 10 ?

This is my CURL command :

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "X-Access-Token: ZmQ780ODRmNDlkMjMzYjA0OTA1Y54545jY5ODQ3MjM0YmNjYjM5ODA1OWU5NTE1YjEwNTdjMjcxMzQ3ZDdjMzMxNDA0ZA==" \
-H "Cache-Control: no-cache" \
-d '{
    "frames": [
        {
            "text": "USDCHF",
            "icon": "i34",
            "index": 0
        }
    ]
}' \
https://developer.myurl.com/api/v1/dev/widget/update/com.myurl.7a9c72294c097a37f0f0a3337f5ad444598f21/1
```

PS: Line by line work perfectly

Thanks